# In HDRI preview, my right sphere is always a very bright white. The render view is also brighter than the material view

Tags: hdri

I also notice that on all example material views I've seen in various posts shows a grayish sphere on the right. Where can I learn more about the relationship between these two spheres? Looking to get an exact match between material view and render view. Thank you.

Comment: Material preview use some default HDRIs while Rendered preview use the HDRI/World and lights you've set. If you want to have the same HDRI in Rendered preview you can go into the Viewport Shading panel (top right) and disable Scene Lights and Scene World, that said it won't render this way, if you want so you need to look for the HDRI that is used by the Material Preview somewhere in your harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking to get an exact match between material view and render view

Material view isn't supposed to match the render. It's merely a test environment for quickly seeing how your materials behave in different lighting environments.

If you want to render the material view as is, use the menu View > Viewport Render Image/Animation.

[Viewport Shading — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/shading.html#material-preview)